# Как реализовать подобную фишку на js, jq?

Tags: javascript, jquery, терминология

Внутри контейнера должно находиться изображение превышающее его размеры. Нужен механизм перемещения изображения по наведению мышкой в пределах контейнера, чтобы увидеть скрытие части картинки. Контейнер имеет свойство
overflow: hidden; (Навели в правую часть контейнера - увидели правую часть изображения). Все должно работать без скачков.

вот разметка+стили.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://foto-babochek.ru/images/risunok-babochki_25.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Нужно плавно менять координаты картинки внутри контейнера `<div class="container">` в зависимости от местоположения указателя мышки на контейнере. То есть при наведении на верхний левый край видно левый верхний край картинки.

Comment: @Darth [Пожалуйста, не отправляйте задающих вопросы в поисковики](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2013/)

Comment: а причем название вопроса к его сути?

Comment: При всем желании вам помочь, трудно понять, что именно вам нужно. Добавьте ваш [mcve] в вопрос, опишите более конкретно желаемый результат

Comment: Ну не знаю. Я вот понял.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

border нужно чтобы было видно края картинки с некоторым запасом.

```js
$( ".container" ).mousemove(function( event ) {
  var border = 50;
  var x=event.pageX-$(this).offset().left;
  var y=event.pageY-$(this).offset().top;
  var newx=(x/$(this).width())*($("img", this).width()-$(this).width()+2*border)-border;
  var newy=(y/$(this).height())*($("img", this).height()-$(this).height()+2*border)-border;
  $("img", this).css({left: -newx, top: -newy});
});
```

```css
.container {
  position:relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container img {
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://foto-babochek.ru/images/risunok-babochki_25.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```